# fancybox: show partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I have the following js code:

```
    function getSelectedPlace(form) { 
        var places = 1           
            $(form).find(":input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("name") === "Signed_Order_B64") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/MyController/MyAction',
                        data: "id=" + places,
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.Result) {
                                ret = response.Message;
                                result = true;
                                $("input[type=hidden][name=email]").val(response.Email);
                                $("input[type=hidden][name=appendix]").val(response.Appendix);
                            } else {

                                // show fancybox
                                result = false;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            result = false;
                        },
                        async: false
                    });

                    $(this).val(ret);
                }
            });
            if (!result) {
                $(submitButton).attr("value", btnText);
                setStateFotBuyButton(false);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I have `if` statement in `success` block. I want show partial view in the fancybox in `else` block. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `content` switch which allows you to set the content of the fancybox to any html:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: response
});
```

Comment: I get error:`The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.` I wrote alert before you code:`alert(response.ViewContent);$.fancybox({
                                content: response.ViewContent
                            });`. and alert shows me: `<div>test<div>`. This is my partial view. Where is a error?

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure what you mean with "partial view" but you could do

```
} else {
 $.fancybox(response,{
  // fancybox options here
 }); // fancybox
}
```